# Tomcat 7.0.23 does not work with tag libraries

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, tomcat7

I have downloaded the latest version of tomcat 7 i.e 7.0.23 as of 1/16/2011. I found that none of my jakarta tag library components are working in jsps. The point of failure is same and consistent in every jsp. It is

```
org.apache.taglibs.input.Select _jspx_th_input_005fselect_005f0 = (org.apache.taglibs.input.Select)_jsp_instancemanager.newInstance("org.apache.taglibs.input.Select", this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

I also wrote a custom tag to see if it is working, I had the same problem for that jsp too.

```
com.ah.util.customtags.SelectTag _jspx_th_hirezon_005fform_005fselect_005f0 = (com.ah.util.customtags.SelectTag)_jsp_instancemanager.newInstance("com.ah.util.customtags.SelectTag", this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

The jsp code is

```
<%@ page extends="com.ah.servlets.BaseJSPServlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/hirezon_form.tld" prefix="hirezon_form" %>
<html>
<body>Test tags
<%
System.setProperty("org.apache.jasper.Constants.USE_INSTANCE_MANAGER_FOR_TAGS", "true");
%>
<hirezon_form:select count="100"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The code for CustomTagSupport class is

```
package com.ah.util.customtags;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;

public class SelectTag extends TagSupport {

    String count;
    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        // This means the JSP must evaluate the contents of any CHild tags
        // in this tag;
        return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
    }
    // This method is called when the JSP encounters the end of te tag
    // implemented by this class
    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {

        String sum = "200000";
        try {
            pageContext.getOut().write("The Sum of first " + count + " numbers is " + sum);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new JspException("Fatal Error: HelloTag could'nt write to the JSP out");
        }
        // This return type tells the JSP page to continue processing
        // the rest of the page
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
}
```

Is there a known bug in Tomcat 7.0.23? I did a lot of research and also tried setting USE_INSTANCE_MANAGER_FOR_TAGS property to true, but I am still getting the same error. Any suggestions will be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it was my jsp. The jsp extends a servlet called BaseJSPServlet. By default when a java class is created for jsp, it extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase, but when you add a page extends directive, your java class will be extending the class you mentioned instead of org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase. So you need to make sure that your parent class does pretty much what HttpJspBase class does.

Here is the sample code of a parent class that can be extended in jsp using page extends directive.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.jsp.HttpJspPage;
import org.apache.jasper.compiler.Localizer;

public abstract class BaseJSPServlet2 implements javax.servlet.jsp.HttpJspPage

{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public final void init(ServletConfig config)
    throws ServletException
  {
    super.init(config);
    jspInit();
    _jspInit();
  }

  public String getServletInfo()
  {
    return Localizer.getMessage("jsp.engine.info");
  }

  public final void destroy()
  {
    jspDestroy();
    _jspDestroy();
  }

  public final void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    _jspService(request, response);
  }

  public void jspInit()
  {
  }

  public void _jspInit()
  {
  }

  public void jspDestroy()
  {
  }

  protected void _jspDestroy()
  {
  }

  public abstract void _jspService(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse)
    throws ServletException, IOException;

}
```